# Can I break a loop using a toplevel break within a Proc in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, break, proc

### Questions

- Why does `break` within a proc jump out of three loops all the way to `puts 8`? It's pretty counter-intuitive.
- Is there a way to make it break out of the innermost loop, that is, to `puts 6`?

### Code

```
3.times do
  puts "outer loop"
  break_proc = proc { break }

  puts 1
  loop do
    puts 2
    loop do
      puts 3
      loop do
        puts 4
        break_proc.call
        puts 5
      end
      puts 6
    end
    puts 7
  end
  puts 8
end
```

> ```
> outer loop
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 8
> outer loop
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 8
> outer loop
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 8
> ```

Comment: You can write `break_proc = proc { raise StopIteration }`. That will cause `6` to be printed after `4`, but you'll have an endless loop following `puts 1`.  The endless loop is not caused by raising the exception, it's merely a reflection of how you've written your code.  (See [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop).)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks. I wrote these endless loops just to illustrate my question. But `raise StopIteration` works only for loops created by `loop`, right? Is there anything that also works with `for`, `while`, `each`, etc.?

Comment: To my knowledge, `loop` is the only method that rescues the `StopIteration` exception. See [StopIteration](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/StopIteration.html).  `break_proc = proc { break }` works fine with `while` (and probably with `for`, but I've never used `for`). `each` is different, as it's not a control structure for looping, but takes a block.

Comment: Short answer: `break` breaks out of the block and stops the method the block is passed to. But, what method is the block being passed to? It is being passed to `Kernel#proc`! So, the `break` breaks out of `Kernel#proc`.

Answer (score 5):

### TL;DR

The behavior you're seeing is a result of attempting to treat a Proc object like a snippet of code passed to [Kernel#eval](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-eval), or thinking that a toplevel break inside a Proc is the same as a bare `break` keyword inside a loop. An explanation for the behavior is provided, but the *real* solution is to avoid doing what you're doing.

### Procs Carry Context

> Why does break within a proc jump out of three loops all the way to puts 8?

This happens because a [Proc](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html) object contains a [Binding](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Binding.html) to the context in which it's created, and the `break` [keyword](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/keywords_rdoc.html) is exiting the iterator block and returning to its calling context. Specifically, you're creating the Proc in the top-level loop here:

```
3.times do
  puts "outer loop"
  break_proc = proc { break }
```

One could be forgiven for thinking that Ruby's `break` just exits a loop wherever its called, but its behavior is more complex than that, especially when you're trying to do something odd like a toplevel break inside a Proc. Your use case for `break` is even covered in *The Ruby Programming Language*, where it says:

> [A break] causes the block to return to its iterator and the iterator to return to the method that invoked it. Because procs work like blocks, we expect break to do the same thing in a proc. We can’t easily test this, however. When we create a proc with Proc.new, Proc.new is the iterator that break would return from. And by the time we can invoke the proc object, the iterator has already returned. So it never makes sense to have a top-level break statement in a proc created with Proc.new[.]
>
> — David Flanagan and Yukihiro Matsumoto. The Ruby Programming Language (Kindle Locations 8185-8192). O'Reilly Media.

When you create deeply nested loops and then complicate that with objects that carry runtime bindings, the results aren't always what you expect. The behavior you're seeing is not a bug, although it may be a misfeature in some cases. You'd have to ask the language designers why it behaves this way if you want a *reason* for the implementation semantics rather an explanation for the behavior you're seeing.

### Breaking Loops

> Is there a way to make it break out of the innermost loop, that is, to puts 6?

Yes, but not with `break` inside a Proc. **Replacing the Proc#call with an actual inline `break` statement does what you expect** and is the "simplest thing that could possibly work," but you can also use [throw](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-throw) and [catch](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-catch) if you want to adjust your nesting level. For example:

```
3.times do
  puts "outer loop"
  break_proc = proc { throw :up }

  puts 1
  loop do
    puts 2
    loop do
      puts 3
      catch :up do
        loop do
          puts 4
          break_proc.call
          puts 5
        end
      end
      puts 6
    end
    puts 7
  end
  puts 8
end
```

This will yield:

> ```
> outer loop
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 6
> 3
> 4
> 6
> 3
> 4
> 6
> ```

and endlessly loop inside the third loop where you `puts 3`.

So, this will do what you're *asking*, but may or may not do what you *want*. If it helps, great! If not, you may want to ask a separate question with some real data and behavior if you want to find a more elegant data structure or decompose your task into a set of collaborating objects.

Comment: Great answer! But in the line after `puts 4` shouldn't there be `break_proc.call` instead of `throw :up`?

Comment: @michau Fixed. I'd moved it inline to test, and in this *specific* case there's no difference in the behavior between inline and inside a Proc, so I'm not really sure why you wouldn't just inline the `throw` rather than adding the overhead and indirection of a Proc. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 3):

Because of context binding `break` escapes from the loop defined at the same level:

```
3.times do
  puts 1
  loop do
    break_proc = proc {|b| break }
    puts 2
    loop do
      puts 3
      loop do
        puts 4
        break_proc.call
          puts 5
      end
      puts 6
    end
    puts 7
    raise 'break other loops'
  end
  puts 8
end
```

=>

```
1
2
3
4
7
1.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': break other loops (RuntimeError)
```

Easiest way to break from your construction - return a boolean from the block indicating if loop should be terminated (`... = proc{ true }`/`break if break_proc.call`), or use `throw`:

```
3.times do
  puts "outer loop"
  break_proc = proc {|b| throw :breakit }

  puts 1
  loop do
    puts 2
    loop do
      puts 3
      catch :breakit do
        loop do
          puts 4
          break_proc.call
          puts 5
        end
      end
      puts 6
      raise 'break the other loops...'
    end
    puts 7
  end
  puts 8
end
```

Comment: The OP asked two questions. You have not answerd either.

Comment: @CarySwoveland confused inner/outer, but in any way `throw/catch` is the way out of complex nested loops, edited for more clarification

Comment: The OP only wants to exit the innermost loop and wants to know why his/code doesn't do that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland example with `catch` above does exactly that and the first part shows why OP's code does not do that - because of context binding (will reword now)

Comment: I hadn't noticed you changed the location of `catch :breakit do`.  Your code correctly prints `6` after `4`, but you show it printing `7`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to break till 6 block you could do this

```
3.times do
  puts "outer loop"
  break_proc = proc { break }

  puts 1
  loop do
    puts 2
    loop do
      puts 3
      loop do
        puts 4
        break
        puts 5
      end
      puts 6
    end
    puts 7
  end
  puts 8
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ruby Folks:**
To use **proc & lambda** in Ruby, kindly consider the following info to use them error-free and use **break or return** with proper understanding:

```
Lambda and non-lambda semantics:
-------------------------------
Procs are coming in two flavors: lambda and non-lambda (regular procs). Differences are:

In lambdas, return and break means exit from this lambda;

In non-lambda procs, return means exit from embracing method (and will throw LocalJumpError if invoked outside the method);

In non-lambda procs, break means exit from the method for which the block is given. (and will throw LocalJumpError if invoked after the method returns);

In lambdas, arguments are treated in the same way as in methods: strict, with ArgumentError for mismatching argument number, and no additional argument processing;

Regular procs accept arguments more generously: missing arguments are filled with nil, single Array arguments are deconstructed if the proc has multiple arguments, and there is no error raised on extra arguments.
```

Ref: https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Proc.html